# Check to see whether a route exist or not in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Can we check/test for existence of a route in Rails?

For example, I want to show a navigation bar that should show all of it's menu URL, regardless the URL exist or not. (to differ between the two, the broken url would use a different styling).

The code to show each menu would look like this:

```
%li= link_to_unless_current menu.name, :controller => menu.controller, :action => menu.action
```

However, Rails would complaint and throw an exception, if the supplied controller and action route doesn't exist.

Does Rails have a function to check before I do the aforementioned code?. Perhaps, something that looks like this:

```
-if some_function_to_check_route_existence?(:controller => menu.controller, :action => menu.action)
```

**EDITED:**

Rather than using "controller" and "action" columns for the menu, i use a "url" column instead. Now, I can do something like this:

```
- if Menu.root
      - for menu in Menu.root.self_and_descendants
        - if menu.url
          %li= link_to_unless_current menu.name, menu.url
        - else
          %li= menu.name
```

I can also use rails function to determine existence of a route, such as:

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this:

```
<% link_to @post.title, post_path if post_path %>
```

Comment: that could work, however my current "menu.controller" and "menu.action" type is string. Do you think it is better for me to parse those string into "something_path" or is there any better function in Rails that takes those string as its argument to check for route existence?

Comment: It would be much easier to make a named route, such as how I did it. If you can make a named route and just check if that exists you should be good to go and you don't have to write out the controller and action everything, hence named route.

Comment: Ok, in the end I use a "url" column to store menu instead of "controller" and "action" column. But I still thought that Rails should provide a function to check whether a route exist or not by supplying controller & action name.

Comment: I can see how you think that but 99% of rails programmers use named routes or get them through `resources`. Good job on being innovative!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `begin rescue` instead checking existances

```
route_exist = true
begin
    url_for(:controller => menu.controller, :action => menu.action)
rescue
    # route not exist
    route_exist = false
end

if route_exist
   ...
else
   ...
end
```

Comment: This Hack save me :)